# Is it possible to declare a function without arguments but then pass some arguments to that function without raising exception?

Tags: python, exception, arguments

In python is it possible to have the above code without raising an exception ?

```
def myfunc():
    pass

# TypeError myfunc() takes no arguments (1 given)
myfunc('param')
```

Usually in php in some circumstances I launch a function without parameters and then retrieve the parameters inside the function.

In practice I don't want to declare arguments in myfunc and then passing some arguments to it. The only one solution I found is `myfunc(*arg)`. Are there any other methods ?

Comment: Why is `myfunc(*arg)` not good enough?

Comment: I'm guessing yuri doesn't (yet) know about *arg

Comment: The implementation need myfunc to be a callback passed to another function which try call it in a list comprehension passing an arguments. So I don't have control over the callback implementation and the user can not-intentionally omit the `*args` (In the code I take care about this event)

Comment: So that would be a bug and raise an exception and the user will remember to put `*args`. Why do you expect php syntax to work in python?

Comment: In that case, I too am not sure why you think *arg isn't good enough.

Comment: @gnibbler @Dana I am tryng to evolve my knowledge from php to python so I compare the two behaviour and test the differences. I think the answer is "no you can't". Thanks for the explainations

Comment: Ah, in that case, one thing to get used to is in python it's generally considered good if there is one official way to do things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable number of parameters in callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662021/variable-number-of-parameters-in-callback)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> def myFunc(*args, **kwargs):
...   # This function accepts arbitary arguments:
...   # Keywords arguments are available in the kwargs dict;
...   # Regular arguments are in the args tuple.
...   # (This behaviour is dictated by the stars, not by
...   #  the name of the formal parameters.)
...   print args, kwargs
...
>>> myFunc()
() {}
>>> myFunc(2)
(2,) {}
>>> myFunc(2,5)
(2, 5) {}
>>> myFunc(b = 3)
() {'b': 3}
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(myFunc)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (args)
              3 PRINT_ITEM
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (kwargs)
              7 PRINT_ITEM
              8 PRINT_NEWLINE
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

And to actually answer the question: no, I do not believe there are other ways.

The main reason is pretty simple: <s>C python is stack based. A function that doesn't require parameters will not have space allocated for it on the stack (`myFunc`, instead, has them in position 0 and 1).</s> (see comments)

An additional point is, how would you access the parameters otherwise?

Comment: The stack comment is besides the point. Python is stack-based, but argument passing (and parsing) is not (arguments are always a single item on the stack, even when there are no arguments.) The reason Python doesn't ignore arguments is because it would **hide errors**.

Comment: It's indeed quite possible I'm misreading what dis tells me :)

Answer (score 16):

There are two ways to pass args in

**By Position**

```
>>> def myfunc(*args):
...  print "args", args
...
>>> myfunc("param")
args ('param',)
```

**By Keyword**

```
>>> def myfunc(**kw):
...  print "kw", kw
... 
>>> myfunc(param="param")
kw {'param': 'param'}
```

And you can use a **combination of both**

```
>>> def myfunc(*args, **kw):
...  print "args", args
...  print "kw", kw
... 
>>> myfunc("param")
args ('param',)
kw {}
>>>
>>> myfunc(param="param")
args ()
kw {'param': 'param'}
>>>
>>> myfunc("param", anotherparam="anotherparam")
args ('param',)
kw {'anotherparam': 'anotherparam'}
```

Answer (score 7):

Sure can!

You can define variable length parameter lists like so:

```
def foo(*args):
    print len(args)
```

args is a tuple of your parameters so calling:

```
foo(1,2)
```

gives you the tuple (1, 2) inside your function.

Comment: `args` will actually be a tuple.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function decorator I wrote to do just that, along with an example of usage:

```
def IgnoreExtraArguments(f):
    import types
    c = f.func_code
    if c.co_flags & 0x04 or c.co_flags&0x08:
        raise ValueError('function already accepts optional arguments')
    newc = types.CodeType(c.co_argcount,
                   c.co_nlocals,
                   c.co_stacksize,
                   c.co_flags | 0x04 | 0x08,
                   c.co_code,
                   c.co_consts,
                   c.co_names,
                   c.co_varnames+('_ignore_args','_ignore_kwargs'),
                   c.co_filename,
                   c.co_name,
                   c.co_firstlineno,
                   c.co_lnotab,
                   c.co_freevars,
                   c.co_cellvars)
    f.func_code = newc
    return f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def f(x,y):
        print x+y

    g = IgnoreExtraArguments(f)
    g(2,4)
    g(2,5,'banana')

    class C(object):
        @IgnoreExtraArguments
        def m(self,x,y):
            print x-y

    a=C()
    a.m(3,5)
    a.m(3,6,'apple')
```

Comment: Haha, totally OTT. I love it.  Never thought I'd see the decorator pattern in a python function.  You should add the capability to show the docstring help to complete this piece of art, and add a python3 update.

Answer (score 1):

```
> def vf(a=0):
>     aw = a + 5
>     print(aw)
> 
> vf() result: 5
> vf(5) result: 10
```