# Variable number of parameters in callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback

I am trying to implement a callback system in Python that is similar to how JavaScript can have different numbers of parameters in its callbacks. Ideally, I want to achieve this **without** using `*args` or `**kwargs` in the parameters of my callbacks.

#### My Goal

What I want is something that looks roughly like this:

```py
def callback1(val):
    print(val)

def callback2(x, y):
    print(x, y)

def callback3(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

def foo(callback):
    callback(1, 2, 3) # Always has 3 arguments to pass

foo(callback1)  # Fails. Should print "1"
foo(callback2)  # Fails. Should print "1 2"
foo(callback3)  # Ok. Prints "1 2 3"
```

Perhaps a more verbose way of putting it would be:

```py
# num_params() method isn't real (that I know of), but this is an
# inelegant example of how the callbacks might work if it were
def foo2(callback):
    if num_params(callback) == 1:
        callback(1)
    elif num_params(callback) == 2:
        callback(1, 2)
    elif num_params(callback) == 3:
        callback(1, 2, 3)
```

#### What I Don't Want

I don't want to use `*args` or `**kwargs` in each callback (unless this isn't possible any other way) like the following:

```py
# This is just SO ugly
def callback1(*args):
    print(args[0])

def callback2(*args):
    print(args[0], args[1])

def callback3(*args):
    print(args[0], args[1], args[2])
```

#### JavaScript Equivalent

This is relatively common in JavaScript. For example, one can supply the callback of a `.forEach()` function with 1, 2, or 3 arguments:

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]

// Valid
myArray.forEach((element) => {
   // Do stuff with the element only
});

// Valid
myArray.forEach((element, index) => {
   // Do stuff with the element AND the index
});

// Valid
myArray.forEach((element, index, array) => {
   // Do stuff with the element, index and the whole array
});
```

However, despite my best efforts in Google searching, I have no idea how to implement this in Python (or even in JavaScript for that matter, but that's beside the point; I hope this doesn't come back to bite me).

I would very much like to know if this is possible in Python and/or what the proper term is for this coding technique.

Comment: It’s a bit unusual that the caller adjusts itself to how many arguments the callee can handle… Sounds like this could be designed better so this becomes a non-issue. Can you clarify the use case?

Comment: In Javascript, the caller always passes the same number of arguments; the callee simply doesn’t need to accept them *explicitly*. The callee still needs to conform to the *interface* the caller describes. And Python is more explicit, you *will* have to explicitly accept all arguments.

Comment: Also, to be more elegant, you can replace `print(args[0], args[1], args[2])` with `print(*args)`.

Comment: @deceze I'm trying to write a generic FileChooser popup in Kivy that returns the file name and possibly the file path. There are obviously ways to get around the multiple arguments in this use case, but I was mostly just curious how one might go about implementing it.

Your explanation that JavaScript methods don't need to accept the arguments explicitly and that Python is more explicit makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with args and kwargs? It is the pythonic way to do that. Python is not JavaScript. If you do not like accessing args by indexes like `args[0]`, `args[1]`, etc, you could just define some args like usual, and rest (unused args) - in `*args`:

```python
def callback1(a, *args):
    print(a)

def callback2(a, b, *args):
    print(a, b)

def callback3(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
```

Also you can unpack them in the function:

```python
def callback1(*args):
    a, *rest = args
    print(a)
```

It makes it more verbose inside, but same definition for all callbacks.

Also it's common to name variables, you are not going to use with `_` (underscore) instead of `args`, `rest`, etc.:

```python
def callback1(a, *_):
    print(a)

def callback1(*args):
    a, *_ = args
    print(a)
```

Comment: Your first method is much more Pythonic than my answer.

Comment: @Selcuk well, we came with almost the same answers :) At first I thought about named args too.

Comment: Thanks! Your code looks way better than how I was imagining. I was unfamiliar with the `*_` trick, it looks really nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can define all your callback functions using the same number of arguments, i.e.:

```
def callback1(val, b=None, c=None):
    print(val)

def callback2(x, y, c=None):
    print(x, y)

def callback3(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
```

Alternatively you can unpack `*args` within functions:

```
def callback1(*args):
    val, _, _ = args
    print(val)

def callback2(*args):
    x, y, _ = args
    print(x, y)

def callback3(*args):
    a, b, c = args
    print(a, b, c)
```

Finally, you can get creative using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).